# android create pdf file from html text

Tags: android, html, pdf, itext

Here is my code in order to convert html into pdf:

```
public boolean create (String htmlText, String absoluteFilePath) {
try {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance
            (document, new FileOutputStream(absoluteFilePath));
    document.open();

    // Fixing xhtml tag
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); // obtain a new Tidy instance
    tidy.setXHTML(true); // set desired config options using tidy setters
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    tidy.setCharEncoding(Configuration.UTF8);
    tidy.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlText.getBytes(), output);
    String preparedText = output.toString("UTF-8");

    Log.i("CHECKING", "JTidy Out: " + preparedText);

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(preparedText.getBytes());
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document,
            inputStream, null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), new MyFont());

    document.close();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    File file = new File(absoluteFilePath);
    if(file.exists()) {
        boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
        Log.i("CHECKING", "PDF isDeleted: " + isDeleted);
    }
    LOGGER.error("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

}

It works for this following htmlText

```html
   <p dir="ltr"><br>
wwwww<br>
--- <br>
Sent bys.</p>


<p>Original message:</p>
<blockquote>
<strong>From: </strong>
nakhmedov@s.com
<br/>
<strong>Sent: </strong>
Dec 1, 2014 5:10:19 PM
<br/>
<strong>
To: 
</strong>
ssss
<br/>
<strong>Subject: </strong>
test
<br/>
<br/>
<p dir="ltr">
<br>
123<br>
--- <br>
ssssssss.</p>
</blockquote>
```

And it doesn`t work this following htmlText:

```html
<p dir="ltr"><br>
123<br>
--- <br>
Sent by ss.</p>


<p>Original message:</p>
<blockquote>
<strong>From: </strong>
Navruzbek Akhmedov <akhmedovnavruzbek@gmail.com>
<br/>
<strong>Sent: </strong>
Dec 1, 2014 5:14:36 PM
<br/>
<strong>
To: 
</strong>
Navruzbek Akhmedov <nakhmedov@sss.com>
<br/>
<strong>Subject: </strong>
test
<br/>
<br/>
<div dir="ltr">12345</div>
</blockquote>
```

Please help me why it works differently and it gives an error for secon htmlText `document has no pages` and outputstream is empty after this `tidy.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlText.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")), output);`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did i miss smth? Maybe html text is not valid which is not working!

Comment: are you using iText to convert pdf  ?

Comment: @Hunt Yes :)     ```compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.3'
    compile 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.3'
    compile 'jtidy:jtidy:4aug2000r7-dev'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue recently. The problem was `Navruzbek Akhmedov <akhmedovnavruzbek@gmail.com>` in html text. iText lib seems to me sees `<akhmedovnavruzbek@gmail.com>` like HTML tag. It doesn't have actually in html tag list then gives error. That's all! :)))))))))))))))))))